# Ask Question and Last Seen Time Discrepancy

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity

I noticed a question where someone asked it **8 minutes ago** but their profile stated they were last seen **23 minutes ago** so there's a discrepenacy I suppose or maybe this is as expected per however this functionality works behind the scenes.

**Asked**

[image]

**Last Seen**

[image]

**Question:** Is this normal and if so what causes this and why does it work that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261614/295684) - that time is only updated every 15 minutes to keep things fast on the server side:

> The rationale is that this number is tracked to give folks a rough idea of whether a given user is still active; the primary implementation concern is raw speed, not accuracy.